# HSpacer y Vspacer de IntelliJ se muestran como un cuadrado blanco

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica

Ya he usado más veces estos componentes en distintos proyectos y nunca me han dado problemas, me gustaría saber como podría conseguir que no se vean al ejecutar la aplicación. De momento la única manera que he encontrado ha sido cambiar el color de fondo a default. Adjunto fotos de como se ven y la jerarquía de contenedores.[image][image]